# Sectors of a Circle

Tags: trigonometry, circles

I am programatically drawing sectors of a circle with radius 55 on a cartesian plane which runs from -55 to 55 on the x and y axes.  I would like the first sector to be drawn at 0,55.

I know I can calculate the x,y values using using:

```
x=radius * cos(angle) 
y=radius * sin(angle)
```

Further, I know that I can multiply x * -1 to go in a clockwise fashion around with the remnaing sectors.

This works great however, the first sector is positioned at -55,0 on the plane.

How do I adjust these caculations so that the first sector starts at 0, 55 and subsequent sectors go around in a clockwise fashion from this point?

Comment: Negate $y$ instead of $x$.

Comment: @DanielFischer if I negate y, then I can start my first sector at 55,0 in a clockwise fashion. What do I have to do to start the first sector at 0, 55

Comment: Ah, sorry, I didn't pay attention and thought you wanted to start at $(55,0)$. To start at $(0,55)$, swap $\sin$ and $\cos$, $x = r\cdot \sin \varphi$ and $y = r\cdot \cos \varphi$ for clockwise, negate $x$ for anti-clockwise.

Comment: @DanielFischer Please post this as an answer so I can assign you credit!  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you have
incorrectly computed the offsets
into your plotting area.

If the center of the area
is supposed to be $(0, 0)$
and the array is
111 by 111 (2 x 55+1),
when you compute
$x$ and $y$,
you have to be careful
when you map those
into your plotting area.

For example,
usually $x$ goes left-to-right
and
$y$ goes bottom-to-top,
but your array to be displayed
may have
its $y$ going top-to-bottom.